# -bash: Setting: command not found - error when opening iterm

Tags: bash, command

I keep receiving this error message each time I open a new tab in iterm:

```
-bash: Setting: command not found
```

Not sure how to fix this. I think it may have to do with `.bashrc` file that I recently edited.

Comment: Maybe have a look at your `.bashrc` file to see if it tries to run a command called `Setting`.  Is this maybe a comment that is lacking a `#` character?

Comment: If this is on macOS, you should also check `.bash_profile` since `bash` is usually started as a login shell on that platform.  Also, _please_ don't post images of text.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will also check .bash_profile. I am new to this site. Ive see other posts with photos of text, is there a specific reason why you recommend not to post them? I thought it would help to determine the issue.

Comment: The contents of the file(s) and what you are seeing in the console may well be important for us to take part of, but post these as _text_ rather than as screenshots.  See e.g. https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086 which describes the issue with this.

Comment: Text is better than a photo of text, because text is easier to read: It does not suffer from low resolution, it is quicker to download, it can be translated, it can be read aloud, it can be pasted…

Comment: I recommend that you change your github api key. You have looked a lot of information, about it. I don't know exactly what it is, but the number of possibilities low, such that I could probably guess, if I tried.

Answer (score 1):

That error message means Bash tried to run a command literally called `Setting`, i.e. a line that starts with that word.

Bash reads/can read a number of files as startup files, including at least `/etc/profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc` (depending on how it's started, see [Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files) in the online reference), plus many distributions have `/etc/profile` also read the files in `/etc/profile.d/`.

You'll need to look into those to find the offending line.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the assistance! There was a missing # symbol in front of the code for python setting in .bash_profile.

# Setting PATH for Python 3.7 is the corrected command line.

Then enter source .bash_profile command after edit.

source ~/.bash_profile